# Program Working On C:\ But Not E:\

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a simple program in VB 2017 that is meant to gather data about my computer's internet connection to be used in a later script, in an attempt to fix an ip issue. The program is meant to be run from my Desktop, which is on my E:\ Drive instead of C:\ On the main drive (C:), the program executes perfectly and outputs the wanted information into a text file, but on E:, the program simply creates the text files, but leaves them blank. The code is as follows:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Creates path for output file & cmd process
    Dim path As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\ExIpOutput.txt"
    Dim path1 As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath() & "\Ipconfig.txt"
    Dim pathSub As String = path.Substring(2, 3)
    Dim path1Sub As String = path1.Substring(2, 3)

    'Creates output files
    Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
    fs.Close()
    Dim fs1 As FileStream = File.Create(path1)
    fs1.Close()

    'Declares the ExIP Program
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .Verb = "runas",
        .FileName = "Cmd",
        .Arguments = "/c" & "nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com" & "> " & path
    }
    'Attempts to run the program
    Process.Start(psi)

    'Declares the IPConf Program
    Dim psi1 As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .Verb = "runas",
        .FileName = "Cmd",
        .Arguments = "/c" & "ipconfig /all" & "> " & path1
    }
    'Attempts to run the program
    Process.Start(psi1)

End Sub
End Class
```

What I've tried/Debugged:

I originally thought it was an issue with the path, being `E:\\` Instead of `E:\`, but after writing an annoyingly complex Function to repair the path, the same result occurred. I am running in both locations with administrative permissions, and the same exact .exe file. The command prompt seems to run fine. Not sure what's up.

Comment: We're not a debugging service. You debug first and if you still can't fix the issue then you provide us with all the relevant information you gathered while debugging.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Will edit I've been debugging for days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting the output of nslookup and ipconfig to a path without quoting, so maybe your location on drive E:\ contains spaces, which would prevent nslookup to write to correct file.

Maybe it would good to provide the actual value of "path" and "path1".

If this is not the case, try to open a command prompt as administrator and try to execute the exact same command with the same paths to verify it works.

Comment: The program is written to be implemented to other locations, so the 'exact value' of the paths may change, which is why I am using a variable instead of an exact, good advice though. I do think this may be the problem, but I do not not how to solve it :/

Comment: I think I may have figured out a solution. I can append the string with quotes on both the start and end before it is referenced in the command prompt, and that should prevent the spaces in the path from screwing up the command. Will post a formal answer if/when it works

Answer (score 1):

```
        .Arguments = "/c" & "nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com" & "> " & path
```

shall look more like

```
        .Arguments = "/c " & "nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com " & "> " & path
```

and

```
        .Arguments = "/c" & "ipconfig /all" & "> " & path1
```

shall look more like

```
        .Arguments = "/c " & "ipconfig /all " & "> " & path1
```

Also I would follow the advise above to consider that spaces may be in the path.

Comment: I made the changes, not sure it would have affected much, but any little bit helps :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following the tips from both @AlessandroMandelli and @wech ... I wrote a (way too long) appending section of the program to put quotes into the path, making sure spaces won't screw up the program:

```
    'Appends path1 string with quotes to fix spacing
    Dim pathIns As String = """"
    Dim path1F As String = path1.Insert(0, pathIns)
    path1 = path1F

    Dim path1FIns As Integer = path1.Length()
    Dim path1FF As String = path1.Insert(path1FIns, pathIns)
    path1 = path1FF

    'Appends path string...
    Dim pathF As String = path.Insert(0, pathIns)
    path = pathF

    Dim pathFIns As Integer = path.Length()
    Dim pathFF As String = path.Insert(pathFIns, pathIns)
    path = pathFF
```

And.. It worked! The program now yields the same results as it would from a path with no quotes! Final product/project can be viewed [here](https://pastebin.com/uBD1W6Cp)